# EAL: Cannot obtain physical addresses: Permission denied. Only vfio will function

Tags: dpdk

I am just trying to run helloworld in dpdk. I am getting this weird error however I performed all the steps in set up scripts as well as build from source but still getting the error:

```
dpdk@dpdk-vm:~/Desktop/dpdk-stable-17.08.1/examples/helloworld/build$ ./helloworld -c 1 -n 1 
EAL: Detected 1 lcore(s)
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Cannot obtain physical addresses: Permission denied. Only vfio will function.
EAL: WARNING: Master core has no memory on local socket!
error allocating rte services array
EAL: FATAL: rte_service_init() failed

EAL: rte_service_init() failed

PANIC in main():
Cannot init EAL
5: [./helloworld(_start+0x2a) [0x5555a79f366a]]
4: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1) [0x7ff3176151c1]]
3: [./helloworld(+0x54f6d) [0x5555a79eef6d]]
2: [./helloworld(__rte_panic+0xbd) [0x5555a79ea467]]
1: [./helloworld(rte_dump_stack+0x2e) [0x5555a7a41a7e]]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

You need to run DPDK applications as root. Please refer to the DPDK Getting Started Guide:

http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/linux_gsg/enable_func.html#running-dpdk-applications-without-root-privileges

Comment: People are strange (cit.) :)

Comment: Use sudo dpdk-replay http.cap 0000:01:00.0 where http.cap is the pcap file you want to send.